# Tree Sql print types

Tags: sql, database

You are given the table Tree, print each node and it's type

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: looks like a homework. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use CTE to do recursive query
Read this [Topic](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) to get more informaions and examples.